# Error on datagrid while right clicking ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

Hi I've added a contextMenuStrip on a dataGrid in WindowsForm, but first time after right click, form minimize.
I re-open it and now right click show me contexMenuStrip.
Can you give me a solution?
Regards.

EDIT: I've added another contexMenuStrip to another dataGrid and I see that first click minimize form (but not if I use .showDialog() command), but all the other works, why?

Comment: Is there something in your code that is making the form minimize?  That doesn't sound like the default behavior.  It might help if you can post the code you are using (either in the question, or if it is very long, at https://gist.github.com

Comment: Hi, I never minimize the form in the program...

Comment: Can you show us the code?  It would make it much easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `FormWindowState.Minimized` in your whole project, set break point there, run debugger and look, if your program runs there.